# How to automate the android phone back button using appium on emulator

Tags: java

I have recently started working on test automation for a native mobile application on Android using Appium(java client library). I haven't been able to figure out any means to automate or create a gesture for using the Phone back button to go back to the previous page of the app. Is there any driver function that can be used? I tried following code,

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

by checking other posts, but it did not work for me. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use following code for go back.

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```